# How do I segment the path of transforms from one vector space to another such that applying n such transforms will be equal to one complete transform?

Tags: matrices, algorithms

I am trying to make a series of matrix transforms which will convert from one vector space ($X_1$) to another ($X_2$) via $n$ sets of translations and rotations.  The idea is to determine the translation of $X_1$ such that it's origin will be on top of $X_2$ (we'll call that $\overrightarrow{D}$), then find the rotations which will make $X_1$ = $X_2$.  This will be an array (we'll call it $d$) of 0 to 2 tuples consisting of the angle and rotation axis $(a, \overrightarrow{r})$ (the array would be empty if if the vector spaces are at the same angle, 1 if they differ only by a single rotation, or 2 if they differ by 2 orthogonal rotations).  To make this easier, I'll make $X_2$ the basis from which most of the operations take place by multiplying by $X_2^{-1}$ and then recover it afterwards.

The idea is that once I have these, I should be able to take this information and then divide the translation and angle by $n$, then create the matrices $D_n$ and $R_n$, apply these one after another to form a discreet path of transforms to get from $X_1$ to $X_2$. I.e. $X_2 = X_1 (R_n D_n)^{n}$.

Even though this intuitively seems to make sense, I wasn't sure it would be possible.  So I tried it and got it partially working (it works for $n = 1$ but not exactly for $n > 1$, though it is kind of close).  I'm pretty sure that this is caused by my assumption which is that this these transforms can be broken up in this way.

To show you what I'm doing in a more math/algorithmic way, let me first define the following operations:

1. $O(T) = \overrightarrow{v}$, gets the vector that points to the origin of vector space $T$.
2. $P(\overrightarrow{v}) = T$, creates the translation matrix to move the vector space over $\overrightarrow{v}$.
3. $R(a, \overrightarrow{r}) = T$, creates a rotation transform with angle $a$ and rotation axis $\overrightarrow{r}$.
4. $angle(v_1, v_2) = cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\overrightarrow{v_1} \cdot \overrightarrow{v_2}}{\|v_1\|\|v_2\|}\right)$, angle between vectors.
5. $concat(a_1, a_2) = a_3$, is the concatenation of array $a_1$ and $a_2$ in left to right order.
6. $generate(a, i) = T$, creates a transform matrix where the array is reduced by applying the $R$ operation above to each element and then multiplying each element with it's next.  The $i$ is what you divide the angle element by. E.g.

   $generate([(90^{\circ}, [1,0,0]), (90^{\circ}, [0,1,0])], n)\\
        = [R(90^{\circ}/n, [1,0,0]), R(90^{\circ}/n, [0,1,0])]      \\
        = R(90^{\circ}/n, [1,0,0]) * R(90^{\circ}/n, [0,1,0])$

My 'code' is as follows:

1. Describe vector spaces relative to $X_2$.  Note that $X_2 = I$.

   $X_1' = X_2^{-1} * X_1\\
    X_2' = X_2^{-1} * X_2$
2. Get the transform which will place $X_1$'s origin to $X_2$'s origin.

   $ Q = P(-O(X_1))$
3. Place $X_1'$ on $X_2'$.  Let $A$ be the the accumulator for the next loop.

   $X_1'' = Q X_1'\\
   A = X_1''$
4. For each vector in the array $[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]$ get the angles and rotation vectors between $\overrightarrow{v} A$ and $v$. When angle isn't 0, put the tuple at the beginning of the description array ($d$).

   $for \overrightarrow{v} in [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]                \\
   \ \ a = angle(\overrightarrow{v} A, \overrightarrow{v})                     \\
   \ \ if\ a \neq 0                                                            \\
   \ \ \ \ \overrightarrow{r} = \overrightarrow{v} A \times \overrightarrow{v} \\
   \ \ \ \ d = concat([(a, \overrightarrow{r})], d)                            \\
   \ \ \ \ A = R(a, \overrightarrow{r}) A                                      \\
   \ \ end                                                                     \\
   end$

Just to note, at the end, $A = I$.

Now, if we say $S = generate(d,1)$, then we ge the following:

$  I = S Q X_2^{-1} X_1 \\
X_2 = X_1 S Q          \\
   $

And for $n=1$ it works great, but it turns out that $generate(d, 1) Q \neq (generate(d, n) \frac{Q}{n})^n$. The final calculated vector space of $X_2$ appears to have its angular positions aligned with the actual $X_2$, but the spatial positions isn't quite right.  I.e. only the bottom left 3 numbers in the transform matrix are off by some value.

So, after all of that, my question is, am I on the right track or is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do?

It's been a while since I've done matrix algebra, so I apologise if what I'm describing isn't done very well.  Please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that these operations are actually orthogonal.  Translation happens separately from rotation.  In other words, at each iteration moving towards $O(X_2)$, I only translate.  The rotate is inconsequential to get to the end goal of $X_1$'s and $X_2$'s origins becoming the same.  At each iteration, I can then apply a separate rotation accumulator ($R_a = S_n^i$) that doesn't feed into the translation accumulator ($T_a = Q_n^i$) and apply it when needed.  Where:

- $R_a$ is the rotation accumulator
- $S_n^i = generate(d, n)^i$
- $T_a$ is the translation accumulator
- $Q_n^i = P\left(\frac{−O(X_1)}{n}\right)^i$

Doing it the way I was doing it resulted in $O(X_1)$ curving around $O(X_2)$, because the vector space kept rotating.  Even if the path were to intersect the target (which it wouldn't) a curved path is longer than a straight line, so it wouldn't reach there anyway.

Just a further note, because I was working with the $X_2$ vector space as the global vector space, all matrices that were recovered using the calculations must be surrounded by $X_2 W X_2^{-1}$, where $W$ is any such matrix, when used in the original global vector space.